# Logrotate Postrotate aws s3 Wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sh, logrotate

I am trying to rotate a bunch of log files and upload them to S3 with the `postrotate` command. 
However, it appears that the postrotate script is not expanding the * glob wildcard:

My logrotate configuration:

```
/var/log/application/*.log {
 missingok
  dateext
  size 500M
  notifempty
  copytruncate
  compress
  rotate 1512
  postrotate
     /usr/bin/aws s3 mv /var/log/application/*.gz  s3://mygreatbucket/
  endscript
}
```

The error I see when running logrotate with that configuration:

```
The user-provided path /var/log/application/*.gz does not exist.
```

This is a message from aws cli s3 command. Which I can replicate if I manually run my command:

```
/usr/bin/aws s3 mv '/var/log/application/*.gz'  s3://mygreatbucket
```

(note the single quotes).

What can I do so that the glob wildcard is expanded during the postrotate step?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS cli documentation states that their CLI tool does directly support glob wildcards. Instead you should use --include or --exclude parameters.

I ended up using:

`/usr/bin/aws s3 mv /var/log/application/  s3://mybucket --exclude '*'  --include '*.gz' --recursive`

The --recursive flag is important, otherwise it won't work.